# Can I infer subtypes in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
    public class ConcreteA<B extends AbstractC<D>> {
      public D getD() {...}
    }
```

or even:

```
    public class ConcreteA<B extends AbstractC<?>> {
      public <D> D getD() {return cInst.dRelatedMethod();}
    }
```

But it seems I have to do this:

```
    public class ConcreteA<D, AbstractB extends C<D>> {
      public D getD() {...}
    }
```

Which gets messy if D has its own type parameters. Is there any way to get this type inference working the way I'd like? Does the Java Community Process have improved type inference in the works?

Eligible answers:
1) A type inference solution exists that gives me what I want without resorting to the solution in block #3
2) A reference to any JSR that seeks to improve type inference in an applicable fashion
3) A refutation of the validity of the concept
4) An authoritative declaration that such a JSR does not exist

Comment: `public class A<B extends C<D>>` Is C an *Actual* class in your code?

Comment: Why **on earth** should you be using such generics?

Comment: @EelLee Yes, earth is a terrible planet for such generics. Over here on Mars though, this is very common.

Comment: Meanwhile in a parallel universe...

Comment: Cruncher: Sorry, thank you. C and A are actual classes. B and D are generic types. I'll rephrase the problem.

Comment: Eel Lee: It's a pretty common pattern. I could motivate it by using real types, but I wanted to express the problem as simply as possible.

Comment: (In the real world, D extends a type with generic type parameter B - but that would confuse the formulation of the question, I think.)

Comment: Editorializing here, but if you're not using generics to enforce interesting model relationships at compile time, you're not really exercising the utility of generics.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! For example the following code compiles (although I don't have any idea why the hell someone would need such a strange construction):

```
public class ConcreteA<B extends AbstractC<D>> {
    AbstractC<D> c;

    ConcreteA(B b) {
        c = b;
    }

    public D getD() {
        return c.getE();
    }
}

class AbstractC<E> {
    E e;

    AbstractC(E e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    E getE() { return e; };
}

class D {

}
```

Note that according to your class definition, `ConcreteA`, `AbstractC` and `D` (!) are classes while `B` is just a template parameter. Don't mix this up!

If you want to have `D` as template parameter too, you must explicitely specify this in the class header of `ConcreteA`:

```
public class ConcreteA<B extends AbstractC<D>, D> {
    AbstractC<D> c;

    ConcreteA(B b) {
        c = b;
    }

    public D getD() {
        return c.getE();
    }
}

class AbstractC<E> {
    E e;

    AbstractC(E e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    E getE() { return e; };
}
```

Now, `B` and `D` (and `E`) are template parameters.

Comment: Are you sure it does! How ?

Comment: I should clarify. D is a generic type, so I'm pretty sure you can't use it in either the declaration for c or as a return type for getD().

Comment: @Sage Yes. At least my eclipse does. So I assume javac eats it too.

Comment: @AdamAugusta According to your class descriptor, D is NOT a type parameter but a concrete class. Otherwise the class should be A<B extends C<D>, D>

Comment: @isnot2bad, D is also supposed to be a generic type as the OP is saying. Not a Class type.

Comment: @Sage OK, but then the class definition is wrong as I already said! I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Eclipse and Oracle/OpenJDK do not always agree when compiling generics. Beware!

Comment: @tucuxi Yes I know (with pain). But in that case it's obvious that it should work. I see no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: I'm not mixing them up, isnot2bad, although I'll agree my original formulation was unclear.
Yes, D must be a class the way I wrote block #1, but that's because I'm trying to tease out either A) a type inference solution exists that gives me what I want without block #3 (identical to your solution), B) a reference to any JSR that improves type inference, C) a refutation of the validity of the concept, or D) an authoritative declaration that such a JSR does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The commonest technique to achieve nearly what you are looking from is to pass the `Class<T>` of the class you are wanting as a parameter.

Here's an example but it does not stop with `newInstance`. You can use `T` as normal anywhere inside the `getT` method.

```
public class A<B extends Set<String>> {
  final B b;

  public A(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  // Hard-coded - not the best.
  public String getString () {
    return "";
  }

  // Internally stored so type is retained.
  public B getB () {
    return b;
  }

  // Inferred from a parameter passed as a Class<T>.
  public <T> T getT(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return clazz.newInstance();
  }

}
```

Comment: I use that idiom, but in this case, I need T to be constrained by B, as is the case in the question.Adding T to the class's generic types would solve the problem, but that's what I'm seeking to avoid.

Comment: By way of clarification, if I could do:
public B[0] getD(), where [0] is the ordinal index of type arguments constraining B, that would give me what I want. I don't think that would be an elegant change to Java, though.

Comment: @AdamAugusta - To my knowledge, what you are asking cannot be done - I believe this technique is closest to what you are looking for. Not an *answer* per. se. but a possible half-way method.

Comment: A useful paradigm in a different case, I agree.